# How to get whatsapp profile picture using contact number

Tags: whatsapp

is there any whatsapp api/url to get whatsapp profile picture of any user using contact number like facebook provide open url for get user profile picture using facebook id.

Comment: This might help you : https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API

Comment: i research on it but not found any good solution @VladMatvienko

Comment: Still no solution?

Answer (score 2):

Check it [watools.io](https://watools.io/download-profile-picture). Whatsapp web will give profile picture from contact number (public profile)

Comment: I wonder what API they use...

Comment: @JohnHenry did you find out the API?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't @SachitSharma :(

Answer (score -5):

Check it and solve it !

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/settings/profile/

Update or retrieve your profile settings using the WhatsApp Web Business Tool or by using API calls to the /v1/settings/profile endpoints.

Update Profile: About

To update your profile's About section use the /v1/settings/profile/about endpoint.
Request

Send the text for your profile's About section in the text field of an API call to the /v1/settings/profile/about endpoint.

PATCH /v1/settings/profile/about
{
"text": "your-profile-about-text"
}

Comment: The user asked how to retrieve the picture of the users, not of his own account